# rattle, rapidminer in R vs SPSS

Tags: r

I am recently starting `R` programming and I find it very interesting.
I found the package rattle for R which can handle statistical models without coding.
Also rapidminer can be integrated with R.
I am not advance coder. Is it possible to use tools like rattle and rapidminer with R to perform all tasks which SPSS can do?
Cheers.

Comment: There are some tools like that available, e.g., [Rcommander](http://www.rcommander.com/). But of course they offer only a very small part of R's functionality. I would recommend learning some coding. That would serve you better in the long run.

Comment: of course coding is the most important part. but for some specific purposes like **DNA alignment** toolbox are great help. **Is there any database which present list of tools for R like CRAN for packages**?

Answer (score 1):

I recently started using `R` and found the `Rattle` GUI interface a good gateway to coding in R. You can do much of what you want to do, load data, visualise, clean, run models etc.
The best part is Rattle saves all the underlying R code you are are utilising in the 'Log' tab of the GUI. That way you can learn basic commands you need to learn and save the log as a starting point for building your own `R` scripts.

To install:
`install.packages("rattle", repos="http://rattle.togaware.com", type="source")`

**Edit:** Once installed, to run the GUI:

> library("rattle")
>
> rattle()

[The website for Rattle](http://rattle.togaware.com/).

For other options have a look [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/R_%28programming_language%29#Graphical_user_interfaces).

Comment: Good job for good GUI. It includes machine learning tools. Do u know any toolbox for Bioinformatics?

Comment: Your original question asks for a discipline specific 'toolbox' you can use 'without requiring coding'. To my knowledge, the answer is 'no'. There are non-discipline specific GUI's and >5,000 packages (including discipline specific ones). You might find the content the bioinformatics team at John Hopkins Uni have released on how to learn/use `R` useful. [link](https://www.youtube.com/user/jtleek2007/featured)